# Target line parameters for shortcuts in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts, parameters

I am using Windows 7 and I am looking for a list of the different parameters to use in the Target line of a shortcut in Windows Explorer.

For example:

- /n forces it to open a new window, even if it duplicates a window that is already open.
- /e uses Windows Explorer view (multi-paned)
- /root,X restricts Explorer to showing only the contents of file folder X (and its sub-folders)
- /select,Y automatically selects Y (either a file or folder).

What other parameters exist? I have been searching online and cannot find anything.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can find, you already got all of the possible switches for windows 7 ([source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/130510)). What are you trying to do?